# Html Agility Pack xpath IEnumerable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, xpath, html-agility-pack

I can not add html code, because it is very very big! 5 scrolls or more. Please, follow link in htmlWeb.load().
I look at this code already 2 hours and I can not figure out what is wrong.

```
HtmlWeb htmlWeb = new HtmlWeb {OverrideEncoding = Encoding.Default};
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument document = htmlWeb.Load("https://www.parimatch.com/en/sport/futbol/germanija-bundesliga");
var matches = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr[@class='bk']").
     Select(tr => new FootballMatch()
     {
         Number = string.Join(" ", tr.SelectNodes("./td[1]//text()[normalize-space()]").Select(t =>t.InnerText)),
         Time = string.Join(" ", tr.SelectNodes("./td[2]//text()[normalize-space()]").Select(t => t.InnerText)),
         Teams  = string.Join(" ", tr.SelectNodes("./td[3]//text()[normalize-space()]").Select(t => t.InnerText)),
         Allowance = string.Join(" ", tr.SelectNodes("./td[4]//text()[normalize-space()]").Select(t => t.InnerText)),
         CoefficientAllowance = string.Join(" ", tr.SelectNodes("./td[5]//text()[normalize-space()]").Select(t => t.InnerText)),
         Total = tr.SelectSingleNode("./td[7]//text()[normalize-space()]").InnerText,
         P1 = tr.SelectSingleNode("./td[10]//text()[normalize-space()]").InnerText,
         X = tr.SelectSingleNode("./td[11]//text()[normalize-space()]").InnerText,
         /*P2 = tr.SelectSingleNode("./td[12]//text()[normalize-space()]").InnerText,
         P1X = tr.SelectSingleNode("./td[13]//text()[normalize-space()]").InnerText,
         P1P2 = tr.SelectSingleNode("./td[14]//text()[normalize-space()]").InnerText,
         P2X = tr.SelectSingleNode("./td[15]//text()[normalize-space()]").InnerText*/
     });
```

P2,P1X,P1P2,P2X always null. 
and it is possible to do this code more neater?

When you click on an event , a popup menu appears , this data is read too , but I do not need this . How can I disable this ?

Comment: it's impossible! The fields are the same, but some read , others do not !

Comment: you will be surprised by yourself! Fields are completely identical , but after 11 can not be read !

Answer (score 0):

This is also not the prettiest. But it works. Still some work needs to be done in respect to sperating certain cells. Since some `<td>`s contain `<br>` to separate lines. Hope this helps you moving on.

```
        string xpath = "//tr[@class='bk']";
        HtmlNodeCollection matches = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(xpath);

        List<List<string>> footballMatches = new List<List<string>>();

        foreach (HtmlNode x in matches)
        {
            List<string> mess = new List<string>();
            HtmlNodeCollection hTC = x.SelectNodes("./td");
            if (hTC.Count > 15)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
                {
                    if (i != 5)
                    {
                        mess.Add(hTC[i].InnerText);
                    }
                }
            }
            footballMatches.Add(mess);
        }
```